# Grouping by and aggregating array of objects and maintaining same structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have an array of objects that I am looking to group by a given property and then aggregate through summing the properties. Here is an example of my data:

This is what I have:

```
const teams = [{posteam: 'ARI', week: 1, touchdowns: 2, fieldgoals: 3}, {posteam: 'ARI', week: 2, touchdowns: 4, fieldgoals: 1}, {posteam: 'ARI', week: 3, touchdowns: 1, fieldgoals: 4},{posteam: 'ATL', week: 1, touchdowns: 0, fieldgoals: 2}]
```

This is what I'm looking to make:

```
[{posteam: 'ARI', touchdowns: 7, fieldgoals: 8}, {posteam: 'ATL', touchdowns: 0, fieldgoals: 2}]
```

The "week" value isn't needed because it's only a label, not an actual measure. Otherwise, I'm looking to basically reduce the arrays' objects into one object per `posteam`. I've looked at the `reduce` and `groupby` functions, but neither seems to be the best solution for doing what Python's `groupby` and `agg` functions do. Ideally, I'd like to make this work in instances where there's only one object with a given `posteam` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate into an object with `reduce` then you take the values out of it. Use destructuring to keep `week` out of your aggregations:

```js
const agg = teams =>
  Object.values(
    teams.reduce((o, {posteam, touchdowns, fieldgoals}) => {
      o[posteam] ??= {posteam, touchdowns: 0, fieldgoals: 0};
      o[posteam].touchdowns += touchdowns;
      o[posteam].fieldgoals += fieldgoals;
      return o;
    }, {}));
    
    

console.log(agg(teams));
```

```html
<script>
const teams =
 [ {posteam: 'ARI', week: 1, touchdowns: 2, fieldgoals: 3}
 , {posteam: 'ARI', week: 2, touchdowns: 4, fieldgoals: 1}
 , {posteam: 'ARI', week: 3, touchdowns: 1, fieldgoals: 4}
 , {posteam: 'ATL', week: 1, touchdowns: 0, fieldgoals: 2}];
</script>
```

Comment: I particularly like the `??=` in it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to iterate over and reduce stuff.

I have done it using Maps:

```js
const teams = [{posteam: 'ARI', week: 1, touchdowns: 2, fieldgoals: 3}, {posteam: 'ARI', week: 2, touchdowns: 4, fieldgoals: 1}, {posteam: 'ARI', week: 3, touchdowns: 1, fieldgoals: 4},{posteam: 'ATL', week: 1, touchdowns: 0, fieldgoals: 2}]

teamsMap = new Map();

for(var obj in teams){
    if(teamsMap.get(teams[obj].posteam)){
        var currentObj = teamsMap.get(teams[obj].posteam);
        var newObj = {
            posteam:currentObj.posteam,
            touchdowns:currentObj.touchdowns+teams[obj].touchdowns,
            fieldgoals: currentObj.fieldgoals+teams[obj].fieldgoals
        }
        teamsMap.set(currentObj.posteam,newObj)
    } else {
        teamsMap.set(teams[obj].posteam,{...teams[obj]})
    }
}
var reducedTeams = Array.from(teamsMap.values())
console.log(reducedTeams)
```

Comment: FYI you still have a lone `week` property in your result.